# EXTENSIONS: convert Firefox extension to Safari extension

Tags: firefox-addon, safari-extension, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am trying to convert my firefox extension to a safari extension. To do that, I used these codes `xcrun safari-web-extension-converter /path/to/extension` .
In my package json, I wrote a script :

```
"start:safari": "npm run-script build:safari; xcrun safari-web-extension-converter ./dist --force --copy-resources --project-location ./safari ",
"build:safari": "cross-env TARGET=safari webpack --progress --config webpack.prod.js",
```

When I run 'start:safari' script it opens xcode. Then I build it, there occurs an error:
[image]

Probably because of that, my setIcon API not working. Also there is no error in console. How can I fix that problem? What is the reason?

Comment: Problem with me: I have imported FireFox extension into xcode and build succeeded. But extension is not appearing in Safari Preferences. Any fix for this?

Comment: @MuhammadHaroonIqbal Hi Muhammad you can take a look this link https://www.vshsolutions.com/blogs/convert-chrome-extension-to-safari-web-extension/

Comment: I have followed this tutorial but xcode make iOS project instead of macOS. So this is causing issue.

Comment: @MuhammadHaroonIqbal in Xcode you should pick macOS at the top